# Can I mount disc in Windows style?

Tags: windows, mount, style

I wish to use Windows mount style in Ubuntu, i.e.

```
/C/ mount point
/F/ mount point
```

I know it is not about standards, but may ease user expluatation.
Does this method have any issues from technical side?

Comment: Linux allows colons in filenames, so you could even do `/C:/`.

Comment: Linux *allows* colons in filenames, but it might make it hard to use them with `PATH`.

Comment: Good, but does this mount style cause any programms to be unstable, or prevent from future access to such drives?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can name your mountpoints pretty much any way you want (although there are conventions on "what is *usually* stored/mounted under what path"); note however that you'll always need a `/` (root) filesystem to mount them *to*. I cannot vouch for *each and every* program to remain stable (programmers are lazy and prone to unreasonable assumptions), but overall there shouldn't be much problems.

However, the conventions mean that a lot of software is looking for stuff in the usual places - e.g. for "Windows style" mounts, the folder /media is used (many programs check it for "mounted drives"); if you mount your drives elsewhere, they'll be accessible, but you'll need to remember where you've put them ;)

Note that programs installed through package manager(s) usually reside in `/usr`; if you're looking to change *this*, it might be a bit more work (but still ultimately possible).

It is also possible to "bind mount" a filesystem or its part, making the files accesible in multiple ways - e.g. you could have `/home/user` accessible as `/U/` by doing `mount --bind /home/user /U` ; for details, see http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts